# how to call a controller from a javascript method?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

here's my javascript code:

```
function find_country(){

        var country_name = document.getElementById('searchBox');
        if(country_name == "")
    window.location.href = "https://localhost/teacherprivate";
        if(country_name != "")
    window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('country-');?>"+country_name;
    }
```

and here's my route:

`$route['country-([a-zA-Z_-]+)']='Countries/get_countries_by_searchword/$1/$2';`

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: when i press the search button it keeps me on the default controller

Comment: would it be possible to change your url like in: `window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('country');?>/"+country_name;` ?

Comment: no, still not working

Comment: of course it doesn't work, it was just a question, IF you may change your link structure

Comment: and how should i change it?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to make a request to `localhost` make sure to use `http://` not `https://`. you can also simply request `/teacherprivate` which tells the browser to reuse the protocol and hostname.

you also need to include this forward slash on the case where country name is not blank so

```php
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('county-');?>"+country_name;
```

becomes

```php
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('/country-');?>"+country_name;
```

and `window.location.href = "https://localhost/teacherprivate";` becomes `window.location.href = "/teacherprivate";`

additionally, you are storing the document element itself, you want its value: `"+country_name.value;`

Comment: https://localhost/aalamatlas/country-[object%20HTMLInputElement] when i press the button it toke me to this url, why?

Comment: and i didn't get what you said above, how can i request (/teacherprivate)?

Comment: oh yeah, you need the value of the element, i updated my answer to be `+country_name.value`

Comment: thank you very much, but the route still not working

Comment: when you click the button does it go to the right url at least?

Comment: yes, like that https://localhost/aalamatlas/country-Greenland

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['country-([a-zA-Z_-]+)']='Countries/get_countries_by_searchword/$1/$2';
```

this route doesn't have any variable data to be sent via $1/$2

But you can change your link structure into:

```
window.location.href = "<?php echo base_url('country/');?>"+country_name;
```

then this routes combo will work:

```
$route['country']='countries/get_countries_by_searchword';
$route['country/(:any)']='countries/get_countries_by_searchword/$1';
```

The first one covers cases where there is no *country_name* value, the second responds to *country_name* having a value.

in your controller's *Countries.php* function *get_countries_by_searchword()* the variable `$country` corresponds to `$1`. You write it like this:

```
get_countries_by_searchword($country=''){
  if($country){
    // do something with $country
  }else{
    // handle empty $country 
  }
}
```

Info about [Codeigniter Uri Routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Comment: maybe yor CI base_url is set incorrectly, try a relative path  `window.location.href = "/country/"+country_name;` also check if country_name has a value, otherwise the route is not working